# Move semantics and reference semantics

Tags: c++, tree, move-semantics

I'm writing a tree-like container, where each "node" has a list with branches/subtrees, currently my head looks like:

```
class _tree {
public:
    typedef _tree* tree_ptr;
    typedef std::list<_tree> _subTreeTy;

    explicit _tree(const _ValTy& v, const _NameTy& n); //create a new tree
    _tree(const _ValTy& v, const _NameTy& n, tree_ptr _root); 
         //create a new tree and add it as branch to "_root".

    ~_tree();

    void add_branch(const _tree& branch); //add by copy
    void add_branch(_tree&& branch); //add by move
private:
    _subTreeTy subtrees;
    _ValTy value;
    _NameTy name;
};


_tree::_tree(const _ValTy& v, const _NameTy& n, tree_ptr _root)
    : root(_root),
    value(v),
    name(n)
{
    _root->add_branch(*this); //not rvalue(???)
}
```

Now the second constructor would create a tree inside `_root` - however how does this work with calling (ignore private violation):

```
_tree Base(0,"base");
_tree Branch(1, "branch", &Base);
Base.subtrees.begin()->value = 8;
std::cout << Branch.value;
```

How would I make it so that `Branch` & `*Base.subtrees.begin()` refer to the same node? Or should i go the other way. Use `add_branch()` to CREATE a branch/subtree?

Comment: Identifiers that start with underscore followed by an upper-case letter are reserved for the implementation. And look ugly.

Comment: What does it have to do with move semantics?

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the title a bit as it wasn't very informative (also other minor changes). Hopefully this still conveys what your question is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move semantics is about moving the internals of an object, not the object (as a typed piece of memory) itself. It's best to think about it in terms of values and invariants, since C++ still has value semantics even when moving is taken into account. This means:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> first(new int);
// invariant: '*this is either null or pointing to an object'
// current value: first is pointing to some int
assert( first != nullptr );

// move construct from first
std::unique_ptr<int> second(std::move(first));

// first and second are separate objects!
assert( &first != &second );

// New values, invariants still in place
assert( first == nullptr );
assert( second != nullptr );

// this doesn't affect first since it's a separate object
second.reset(new int);
```

In other words, while you can convert the expression `*this` to an rvalue by doing `std::move(*this)` what you want cannot be achieved right now since `std::list<_tree>` uses value semantics and `_tree` has value semantics itself. `*Base.subtrees.begin()` is a distinct object from `Branch` and as things are modifications to the former won't affect the latter.

Switch to reference semantics if that's what you want (or need), for instance by using `std::shared_ptr<_tree>` and `std::enable_shared_from_this` (you'd then use `_root->add_branch(shared_from_this())` inside the constructor). I wouldn't recommend it though, this could get messy. Value semantics are very desirable in my opinion.

---

With value semantics, using your tree could look like:

```
_tree Base(0, "base");
auto& Branch = Base.addBranch(1, "branch");
```

That is, `addBranch` returns a reference to the newly constructed node. Sprinkling some move semantics on top:

```
_tree Base(0, "base");
_tree Tree(1, "branch); // construct a node not connected to Base
auto& Branch = Base.addBranch(std::move(Tree));
// The node we used to construct the branch is a separate object
assert( &Tree != &Branch );
```

Strictly speaking if `_tree` is copyable move semantics are not necessary though, `Base.addBranch(Tree);` would work too.